# JOIN multiple tables in single query using LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: php, sql, pdo, left-join

I'm having difficulties using the LEFT OUTER JOIN in multiple tables.

My tables are: `countries`, `customer_info`, `package_types`, `service_types` and `shipping_info`

This is my code so far:

```
$sql = "SELECT shipping_info.shipping_id, shipping_info.weight, shipping_info.width, shipping_info.height, shipping_info.length, shipping_info.cost, shipping_info.status, 
service_types.service, package_types.package_type, countries1.country AS fromCountry, countries2.country AS toCountry, countries3.country AS resiCountry, customer_info.name, customer_info.address
, customer_info.city, customer_info.postcode, customer_info.zipcode, customer_info.phone, customer_info.email, customer_info.country
FROM shipping_info 
LEFT OUTER JOIN service_types ON shipping_info.service_type = service_types.serviceType_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN package_types ON shipping_info.package_type = package_types.packageType_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN customer_info ON shipping_info.customer_id = customer_info.customer_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN countries AS countries1 ON shipping_info.from_loc = countries1.country_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN countries AS countries2 ON shipping_info.to_loc= countries2.country_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN countries AS countries3 ON shipping_info.to_id = countries3.country_id";

$statement = $con_db->query($sql);
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
```

I'm getting a **fatal error** in my final line and I believe that's because $result is null. But I'm unable to figure out the error.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: We need way more information.  There should be at least a minimal message to go with that fatal error.  Then, try other things to see what could be making `$result` null, if that's what's going on.  Your query appears minimally correct (no obvious syntax errors), although you could probably make most of the table references regular `(INNER) JOIN`s (for example, you're unlikely to ship to countries you don't have in your db).  I'm also a little worried that you appear to have two country destination columns in `shipping_info`, but having them is unlikely to cause the problem directly.

Comment: Try running phpMyAdmin and pasting the query into the SQL box to see if you get any errors. If no luck then, as previously requested, please tell us the specific error.

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365537/connect-multiple-tables-using-left-outer-join?rq=1

Comment: When clarifying a question please edit the existing one rather than adding a new one.

Answer (score 0):

It may be your query has following manual error:

**tablename** or **fieldname** mismatch